# iOS TapGestureRecognizer -- Multiple Touches Implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

**GOAL:** I like to detect how many fingers the user used to tap the screen.

**Possible Solution:** Use a `UITapGestureRecognizer`. I'd like to just use one recognizer and check the number of touches with `recognizer.numberOfTouches` inside the method it calls. However, it `numberOfTouchesRequired` seems to be a *strictly equal* qualifier rather than a *greater than or equal to* qualifier. i.e. If I set `numberOfTouchesRequired` to 1, my `UITapGestureRecognizer` doesn't respond to 2-finger taps. Therefore, I must create 5 different `UITapGestureRecognizers`, each with a different `numberOfTouchesRequired` (1, 2, 3, 4, and 5).

Is this this optimal solution? It feels hacky to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try subclassing UIGestureRecognizer and creating a custom recognizer that detects how many fingers are on the screen. Here's notes on how to subclass UIGestureRecognizer: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009279-CH1-SW2

Or you could implement the touchesBegan: withEvent method for a view and count the number of touches.

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    int num_touches = [touches count];
}
```

Just make sure that

```
view.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
```